# Can anyone solve this table for me? I want to make in overleaf but does not fit in paper!

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
        \centering 
        \begin{threeparttable} 
            \caption{The fist nine Modes of the Blade}
            \label{tab:PPer} 
            \begin{tabular}{l l l l l l l l l l}  
                
                \toprule 
                \textbf{Mode Number}& 1 & 2 & 3& 4& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9 \\
                \midrule
                \textbf{Frequency [Hz]}&  191.25 & 531.4 & 695 &1108.75 &1140.6 &1304.4 &1986.5 & 2558.6 & 2675.8 \\
                \midrule
                \textbf{Damping ratio $\zeta(\%)$}&  0.46 & 0.93 & 0.21 &1&1&1&1&1&1 \\
                
                \midrule
            \end{tabular}  \label{tabel:3.5}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}`
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *solve*?

Comment: If you want you table to fit to the page, you will find plenty of suggestions here. First have a look at this question: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options)

Comment: it is not fit on a page, it is too long,

Comment: Too long is easy: use longtable (longtable package).  Too wide is more difficult.

Comment: i mean too wide, sorry

Comment: no one knows? still does not fit, too wide in overleaf !

Comment: Overleaf has nothing with your problem. Possible solution you can find in answer on question to which is your question duplicate.  There you will find options as reduce `\tabcolsep` size, use smaller fonts etc. For example, considering to use `small` font size and `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{9}{c} }` seems to be promising approach to solve your problem

Comment: To save even more space, you could additionally allow line breaks in the first column.

Answer (score 1):

does it fit now -- added  `\noindent\hspace{-3cm}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
    \noindent\hspace{-3cm}     
        \begin{threeparttable} 
            \caption{The fist nine Modes of the Blade}
            \label{tab:PPer} 
            \begin{tabular}{l l l l l l l l l l}  
                
                \toprule 
                \textbf{Mode Number}& 1 & 2 & 3& 4& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9 \\
                \midrule
                \textbf{Frequency [Hz]}&  191.25 & 531.4 & 695 &1108.75 &1140.6 &1304.4 &1986.5 & 2558.6 & 2675.8 \\
                \midrule
                \textbf{Damping ratio $\zeta(\%)$}&  0.46 & 0.93 & 0.21 &1&1&1&1&1&1 \\
                
                \midrule
            \end{tabular}  \label{tabel:3.5}
        \end{threeparttable}
    
    \end{table}`
    
\end{document}
```